# Static method issue

Tags: c#

I have a question if the static method Do is shared over all possible instances of Dog, why my other instances cant use Do method to change value inside or see the value will be the same for all instances?

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First value: " + Dog.Do(0));
                Console.WriteLine("After first change: " + Dog.Do(5));

                Dog dog1 = new Dog();
                Dog dog2 = new Dog();


                //cant use why ? i want to see from other instances of Dog about value either k is same for all instances
                //dog1.Do(44);
                //Console.Writeline(dog2.Do(0));

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            public class Dog 
            { 
                public static int Do(int t)
                {
                    int k = 3;
                    k = k + t;
                    return k;
                }
                public int Do2()
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "why my other instances cant use Do method to change value inside or see the value will be the same for all instances?" can you rephrase that more clearly? it is hard to understand what you are asking. What "value inside" are you talking about? `Dog` has no fields, neither static nor instance

Comment: `Static` methods can use `static` variables only, so yes both of those are sticky, i.e. they are shared in all instances.

Comment: the question is why dog1 and dog2 cannot access Do which should be shared accross all Dog instances?

Comment: it means that Do is available only for Dog class and not for instances of Dog because Dog is first oryginal copy and next Dogs are instances and i cannot access it ?

Answer (score 7):

`static` methods don't belong to any instance. They belong the class itself. You need to specify your class name to call `Do` method.

For more information about *static* and *instance* methods, please refer to documentation:

- [Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)
- [10.2.5 Static and instance members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [10.5.2 Static and instance methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since the method is static, there is just one method, not a method for each instance. You can call static methods using the class:

```
Console.WriteLine(Dog.Do(42));
```

Comment: the question is why dog1 and dog2 cannot access Do which should be shared accross all Dog instances? Do2 is only for each instance but Dog should be shared accross all instances am i wrong?

Comment: You can call Do inside a non-static method of dog1 and dog2, but not like dog1.Do(). Do belogs to a class and not to an instance, therefore you call the method Dog.Do and not dog1.Do.